# About the use of "whenever" in the headline "Why Working Till Whenever Is a Risky Retirement Strategy"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, headlinese

Does *whenever* in the construction:

> Why Working Till **Whenever** Is a Risky Retirement Strategy

play the role of an adverb?

And more generally is it grammatical to follow up a preposition with an adverb?

Source: [link](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/16/business/retirement-layoff-working-longer.html?fallback=0&recId=1Lk6HIYDfpRJIqqCc4MiwCT66bg&locked=0&geoContinent=AF&geoRegion=19&recAlloc=story&geoCountry=DZ&blockId=home-featured&imp_id=60470198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Whenever" here is a noun referring to some nonspecific and sort of arbitrary time. This usage is very contemporary, colloquial, and a bit cheeky, and I can see how it could be confusing.

Imagine this same headline instead using "age 75":

```
Why Working Till Age 75 Is a Risky Retirement Strategy
```

That makes perfect sense, and it's the same construction here-- they've substituted "whenever" which has a meaning like: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
"So, when are you planning to retire?" 
"Oh I don't know... I guess.. whenever."
```

Comment: Actually, What confused me was the fact that no dictionary defined *whenever* as noun.

Comment: I suspect the nounification of "whenever" is very recent. It can play either role in the same way that "tomorrow" can be an adverb or a noun.

Comment: I think it may be a relative pronoun, or rather a relative pronoun (when) and an adverb (ever) in a trench-coat